# Autodesk Viewer: XHR redirects to localhost

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

**EDIT 16. Feb. 2024**

**This only happens in the latest viewer version 7.95. <= 7.94 everything works fine. I leave this post for the APS support so they can see it.**

When I use the Autodesk viewer on my site, the XHR request from the viewer to `/derivativeservice/v2/regions/eu/manifest/documentId` suddenly goes to `localhost/derivativeservice/v2/regions/eu/manifest/documentId` instead of the Autodesk server. I spent hours trying to figure out what went wrong, but could not find the problem.

I tried changing the `env` variable for the viewer options (prod, dev etc).

I also made sure to put the urn:` in front of the documentId.

I tried switching to my main branch and suddenly the problem appears there as well (I did not change anything in the main branch). I have no idea why this would happen.

The problem persists in a Docker container as well.

Here is my code:

```
import type APS from "forge-apis";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function useViewerInitializer(
  token: APS.AuthToken,
  versionIds: string[]
) {
  const viewerRef = useRef<Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedView | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeViewer = (
      options: Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedViewInitOptions
    ) => {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => resolve());
      });
    };
    const loadDocument = (documentId: string) => {
      return new Promise<Autodesk.Viewing.Document>((resolve, reject) => {
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
          documentId,
          (doc) => resolve(doc),
          (errorCode, errorMsg, messages) =>
            reject({ errorCode, errorMsg, messages })
         );
      });
    };
    var options = {
      getAccessToken: (
        onSuccess: (accessToken: string, expiresIn: number) => void
      ) => {
        onSuccess(token.access_token, token.expires_in);
      },
    };
    const init = async () => {
      if (token) {
        try {
          var htmlDiv = document.getElementById("forgeViewer");
          if (!htmlDiv) {
            throw new Error("Viewer container is missing.");
          }

          await initializeViewer({ viewerConfig: options });
          viewerRef.current = new Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedView();
          await viewerRef.current.init(htmlDiv, { viewerConfig: options });

          console.log(versionIds);

          const versionIds64 = versionIds.map(
            (vid) => "urn:" + Autodesk.Viewing.toUrlSafeBase64(vid)
          );
          const docs = await Promise.all(
            versionIds64.map((documentId) => loadDocument(documentId))
          );

          const nodes = docs.map((doc) =>
            doc.getRoot().search({ type: "geometry" })
          );

          viewerRef.current.setNodes(nodes[0], {});
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error init:", error);
        }
      }
    };
    init();
  }, [token, versionIds]);
  return { viewerRef };
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions, the 'env' variable in Initializer function was optional, now it's mandatory. Please pass env: 'AutodeskProduction' as shown below:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'AutodeskProduction', getAccessToken }, function () {
   const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container, { extensions });
   viewer.start();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We are sorry to hear this problem is bothering you. Could you please have a try below?

Please try to modify your options by specifying the viewer env and api explicitly like below.

```js
var options = {
  getAccessToken: (
    onSuccess: (accessToken: string, expiresIn: number) => void
  ) => {
    onSuccess(token.access_token, token.expires_in);
  },
  env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
  api: 'streamingV2'
};
```

If your model is host on our EMEA data center, please change `api` value above to `streamingV2_EU` for example:

```js
var options = {
  getAccessToken: (
    onSuccess: (accessToken: string, expiresIn: number) => void
  ) => {
    onSuccess(token.access_token, token.expires_in);
  },
  env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
  api: 'streamingV2_EU'
};
```