# Autodesk Forge App with Node Js. The viewer does not work

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have my first Autodesk Forge app in Node.js. It was working correctly. Since yesterday, it has not rendered my project's BIM 360 Revit models. I use InspireTree. However, it does have access to the project and views, which I can see using console.log in the Visual Studio Code terminal.

The Chrome console tells me there is no access to port 8080, error 400, but this only occurs when rendering the model; the InspireTree schematic does work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear this. There has been a small change in viewer initializer; please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78007823/autodesk-viewer-xhr-redirects-to-localhost/78031453#78031453)